# @Converter() is ignored when I am using it in abstract class

Tags: spring, jpa, converters

I have problem that @Converter() is ignored when I am using it in abstract class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHALLENGE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class AbstractChallenge implements SecretChallenge {
    ...
    @Convert(converter = InstantConverter.class)
    Instant creationTime;
    ...
}
```

If I use it in standard JPA it works as expected.

```
@Entity
public class PasswordResetTokenJPA {
    ...

    @Convert(converter = InstantConverter.class)
    private Instant issuedAt;

    ...
}
```

Here is my converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class InstantConverter implements AttributeConverter<Instant, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(Instant instant) {
        if (instant == null) return null;
        return new Timestamp(instant.toEpochMilli());
    }

    @Override
    public Instant convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp value) {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return value.toInstant();
    }

}
```

Comment: works fine with the JPA Provider I use. Which one are you using? FWIW You can use `@Converter` in any persistable class with 'standard JPA'

Comment: I am using hibernate, hikari for connection pool and i tested it with MariaDB

Comment: I did another test with H2 and I have the same issue

Comment: So report a bug on your chosen JPA provider; what you post is valid code and works in other JPA providers.

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using?

Comment: DataNucleus JPA, but that shouldn't matter if the provider has implemented the JPA spec fully